# Error when using mysql in c

Tags: mysql, c

I'm coding a setup for my "game" server and I use MySQL for database. I getting an error when I create the database + table and the columns. I tested the Mysql code in phpmyadmin and it worked.

Here's a sample of my code: `

```
int area;
char user[100];
char pass[100];
char ip[200];
char tentativaspm;
void mysqlsetup(){


  MYSQL *CON = mysql_init(NULL);
  if (CON == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(CON));
    exit(1);

  }
  if (mysql_real_connect(CON, ip, user, pass,
          NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(CON));
      mysql_close(CON);
      sleep(2);
      userepassmysql();
  }
  printf("Conecao establecida.\n");
  if(mysql_query(CON, "CREATE DATABASE place;")){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(CON));
      mysql_close(CON);
      exit(1);


  }


if(mysql_query(CON, "USE place; CREATE TABLE grid (pixelID int,color int);"){
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(CON));
      mysql_close(CON);
      exit(1);

}
```

And I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USE `grid` CREATE TABLE `grid` (`pixelID` int(11) NOT NULL,`color` int(11) NOT N' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the mysql_query c function doesn't support multiple SQL statements. 
But you can combine the two queries

```
USE [database];
CREATE TABLE grid (pixelID int,color int)
```

into the oneliner

```
CREATE TABLE [database].grid (pixelID INT, color INT)
```

Note replace [database] with the correct database name.

**Solution one**

Using the oneliner

```
if(mysql_query(CON, "CREATE TABLE place.grid (pixelID int,color int);"){
```

**Solution two**

Use the function mysql_set_server_option() function to enable multiple SQL statements.

```
mysql_set_server_option(connection, MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON);
```

Comment: Thank you :D  Have a nice day.